# React app throws 401 error when accessed through safari, but not otherwise

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, safari, mobile-safari, fetch-api

I have a react app hosted in an s3 bucket behind a cloudfront distribution. This talks to a django server. Login works correctly on all browsers (confirmation that credentials are correct, and no fundamental connection issues). Once logged in, the app redirects to a page that does a simple GET request via fetch (to a url that requires authentication). This works successfully on all browsers on desktop (macos) except safari, which gets a 401 unauthorised error. Similarly, I get a 401 unauthorised error on every browser on iOS.

I've tried flushing the DNS of the mac, to no avail. I'm totally stumped. If it didn't work at all, that would be fine, but working everywhere apart from safari?

fetch code:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`${apiRoot}/info`, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Token ${this.props.auth.token}`
      }
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          Name: data.name,
          Email: data.email
        });
      });
  }
```

Comment: Are you testing in private browsing mode, and using `localStorage` to handle auth keys? Safari doesn't provide a `localStorage` object in private browsing mode, and many (all maybe?) iOS browsers, including Chrome, are just UI wrappers around Safari.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst I think you're right about iOS browsers being wrapped safari, but I'm not using private browsing, and the credentials are definitely still in the state.

Comment: Can you show us some code then please? Also what version of Safari and Mobile Safari are you testing on?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst I'll add the fetch to the question, but it's pretty basic. Safari is 12.0.2, and mobile safari is the version that comes in iOS 12.1.2

Comment: @Alex could this potentially be whats going on? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50515514/receiving-401-status-with-safari-not-chrome-in-react

Comment: @Alex Could this describe what you are seeing? https://medium.com/@mrjack/safari-the-fetch-api-and-30x-redirects-23c5610370ca

Answer (score 2):

Add a forward slash to end of your fetch url:

```
fetch(`${apiRoot}/info/`, ...
```

Chrome and Firefox seem to resolve this on their own, but Safari doesn't.