# Receiving 401 status with Safari while loading a an angular webpage only for the first time

Tags: node.js, angularjs, safari, mean

PROBLEM

When using Safari as a browser, rather than Chrome, we receive a 401 status when we load our web application home page,this only happens for the first time on that tab,when we open a new tab and reload the application it loads fine.

The technologies we are using are MEAN stack,all is fine when we use Chrome/Firefox as our browser (no 401 error is given and authentication seems to be fine), but when we switch to Safari, it does not work.

I looked a similar post [Receiving 401 status with Safari not Chrome in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50515514/receiving-401-status-with-safari-not-chrome-in-react) on SO and ensured the endpoints have front slashes

API calls

```
get_change_lifecycle_data(){
    const params = new HttpParams().set('params', this.enteredValue);
    this.http.get('https://change-life-cycle.region02.hoster.company.com/api/change_life_cycle/',{params})
        .subscribe(response => {
        console.log("change data:");
         console.log(response);
         this.newPost = response
        //  this.splice_gerrits();
     });
}
```

FAILED REQUEST:

```
Summary
URL: https://bati.company.com/runtime-es2015.858f8dd898b75fe86926.js
Status: 401 Unauthorized
Source: Network

Request
Origin: https://bati.company.com
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) companyWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.1.2 Safari/605.1.15
Referer: https://bati.company.com/

Response
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Tue, 20 Aug 2019 00:02:58 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Server: companyHttpServer/54b48526
Content-Length: 207
X-B3-TraceId: b39ab56a5e87f4f0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Www-Authenticate: Basic realm="Enter your company OD credentials"
```

SUCCESSFUL REQUEST AFTER OPENING A NEW TAB:

```
Summary
URL: https://bati.company.com/runtime-es2015.858f8dd898b75fe86926.js
Status: 200 OK
Source: Memory Cache

Request
No request, served from the memory cache.

Response
ETag: "5d5b0e97-5a0"
Content-Type: application/x-javascript
Date: Tue, 20 Aug 2019 00:01:36 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 19 Aug 2019 21:03:19 GMT
Server: companyHttpServer/54b48526
Content-Length: 1440
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-B3-TraceId: ecc642668834014e
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
```

UPDATE:--

I was able to replicate the problem by sending a curl request ,I get a 401 error response

```
curl 'https://bati.company.com/runtime-es2015.858f8dd898b75fe86926.js' \
-XGET \
-H 'Origin: https://bait.company.com' \
-H 'Accept: */*' \
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) companyWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.1.2 Safari/605.1.15' \
-H 'Referer: https://bait.company.com/'
```

**401 error response**

```
<html>
<head><title>401 Authorization Required</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>401 Authorization Required</h1></center>
<hr><center>CompanyHttpServer/54b48526</center>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE2:**

```
curl -u username:password 'https://bati.company.com/runtime-es2015.858f8dd898b75fe86926.js' -XGET -H 'Origin: https://ibait.apple.com' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.1.2 Safari/605.1.15' -H 'Referer: https://ibait.apple.com/'
```

**UPDATE3:**

```
api_change_foldscore_data(){
    const username = 'username'; // need to get these values from X-Forwarded-User
    const password = 'password';
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password)
    });
    this.http.get('https://change-life-cycle.hoster.company.com/api/change_fold_score', {headers, params})
        .subscribe(response => {
        console.log("change data:");
         console.log(response);
         this.newPost = response
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the subsequent request (new tab) it is served from memory cache. So it appears to be in cache, not sure how it got there. Could you try clearing all cache in chrome and safari and refresh to see if your new api calls have all the required authorization headers in both browsers?

Comment: I tried in `Safari Private` mode ,entering the username and password always takes me to a blankpage,I see `401 unauthorized` in `web inspector`,I do not see this issue at all in `Google Incognito` or `Mozilla after clearing cache` ,what required `authorized headers` are you referring to?

Comment: I updated the question ,if I append the `username:password` to the curl request ,I see it works, how do I make sure the curl request gets the username and password appended via angular?

Comment: The curl request has nothing to do with angular. What do the succcesful requests look like in chrome? And are the same requests made in safari?